# How to connect iPad app to an app I have running in Windows

Tags: .net, ios, networking, json

I recently picked up a macbook and want to start doing some apps for my ipad. I have a chat client written in c# that interfaces a game I play. What I would like to do is write an app for the ipad that would communicate somehow with my c# app.

What would be the best approach to this? I have never used JSON but is this where I should be looking?

I don't want to spend a ton of time looking in the wrong place, hoping someone here could point me in the right direction.

Comment: where are your C# and ipad apps going to be hosted?

Comment: It may not be such a good idea not to spend a ton of time and seek quick solutions online. You will probably benefit by reading up about 'web services' before going forward with your project.

Answer (score 1):

there are already proven standards that exists to solve this problem such as web-services, soap, and JSON. I would recommend you to use a web-service.

Answer (score -2):

One solution could be Microsoft Azure. You could run a Push Notification Service to enable the communication between your app on windows and your app on your iPad. Services like a RESTful or SOAP service could fit your problem as well, but I don't know your exact problem ;-)

Comment: So you are saying that bouncing something off a remotely hosted cloud so it can communicate to a PC in the same room makes sense?